# Empty 'terms' in 'tax_query' returns an empty array

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, tax-query

I would like a simple search on the products page, so I built a custom WP_Query.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'meta_key'   => 'product_price',
        'meta_value' => array($query_from,$query_to),
        'meta_compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'meta_type' => 'numeric',

        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_categories',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => array( 4, 5 ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_categories',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => 7,
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_tags',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => 9,
            ),
        ),
    );
```

The `product_tags` taxonomy is sometimes empty, and when It's empty the query returns an empty array. What's the best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, what do you expect to happen when `product_tags` are empty? Why not only append it into `$args['tax_query']` whenever it's not empty?

Comment: This is the normal behaviour if you use `AND` relation - if one of the criterias fails, everything fails. Use `OR` instead if you still want to get results, even if one or more criterias fails. But that's the point of search criteria in my opinion: if you want **red Ferrari** specifically but there's no **Ferrari**, would you settle with every other **red** car?

Comment: *The `product_tags` taxonomy is sometimes empty*, what do you mean by *empty*